# How to add parameters to the current url in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location

I got my current url with this

```
   $location.url() which it '/details
```

This time i want to add some params to it like

```
'/details/student'
```

How can i add '/students' to my current url on click,can any one suggest help please.Thanks.

```
  <tabset>
<tab heading="student" ng-click = "changeRoutes('student')">
    <h4>STUDENTS</h4>
    <p>Best students..</p>
</tab>
<tab heading="teacher" ng-click = "changeRoutes('teacher')">
    <h4>TEACHERS</h4>
    <p>Best teachers..</p>
</tab>
```

Comment: Ideally, you should be using either [ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for routing - then use either the `href` or `ui-sref` attribute on the element that is clicked to navigate to the new url

Comment: But i dont have any state declared its a single page html;

Comment: What do you want to happen when `/student` is added to the url? Do you want to navigate to that location?

Comment: No in my html i have 4 tabs in which /student is one.

Comment: When /student happens that tab is opened'

Comment: Can you post your HTML and controller code, it would make this so much easier than trying to fish for what you want

Comment: If you just want to navigate to another url, you can do `$window.location.href = '/details/students'` - in any case, it would very likely be better to use one of the angular-provided routing options with things that have anything to do with urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define router for that like following :-

```
$stateProvider
//considering route.state is your current state and you need to go on student
  .state(route.state + '.student', {
    url: '/student',
    templateUrl: 'app/examples/student/student.tmpl.html',
    controller: 'StudentController'
  });
```

Then inside your details controller you need to move to student like following

```
$scope.baseState.name = $state.current;
$state.go($scope.baseState.name + '.student');
```

By this way you will load templates for all tabs at the time of loading them.